# How to edit the /etc/jitsi/jibri/jibri.conf for jitsi recording on jibri since /etc/jitsi/jibri/config.json doesn't exist anymore

Tags: amazon-ec2, self-hosting, recording, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I’am working on a self-hosting jitsi on a ec2 aws instance, the installation is successfully completed, now i want to record , when configuring jibri i noticed that /etc/jitsi/jibri/config.json is missing, researched a little more on the documentation and found that jibri made some changes and the file to edit is now /etc/jitsi/jibri/jibri.conf , but for my case jibri.conf is empty , tried to copy/paste some code found in here https://docs.easyjitsi.com/docs/confignewjibri/ , but it sill fails to record.
So the question is , is there a reason my jibri.conf is empthy or it is supposed to be that way and how to edit it so jitsi find it ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

jibri.conf

```
jibri {
  // A unique identifier for this Jibri
  // TODO: eventually this will be required with no default
  id = ""
  // Whether or not Jibri should return to idle state after handling
  // (successfully or unsuccessfully) a request.  A value of 'true'
  // here means that a Jibri will NOT return back to the IDLE state
  // and will need to be restarted in order to be used again.
  single-use-mode = false
  api {
    http {
      external-api-port = 2222
      internal-api-port = 3333
    }
    xmpp {
      // See example_xmpp_envs.conf for an example of what is expected here
      environments = [
          {
                name = "prod environment"
                xmpp-server-hosts = ["your.domain.com"]
                xmpp-domain = "your.domain.com"

                control-muc {
                    domain = "internal.auth.your.domain.com"
                    room-name = "JibriBrewery"
                    nickname = "jibri-nickname"
                }

                control-login {
                    domain = "auth.your.domain.com"
                    username = "jibri"
                    password = "JPwd"
                }

                call-login {
                    domain = "recorder.your.domain.com"
                    username = "recorder"
                    password = "RPwd"
                }

                strip-from-room-domain = "conference."
                usage-timeout = 0
                trust-all-xmpp-certs = true
            }]
    }
  }
  recording {
    recordings-directory = "/srv/recordings"
    # TODO: make this an optional param and remove the default
    finalize-script = "/path/to/finalize_recording.sh"
  }
  streaming {
    // A list of regex patterns for allowed RTMP URLs.  The RTMP URL used
    // when starting a stream must match at least one of the patterns in
    // this list.
    rtmp-allow-list = [
      // By default, all services are allowed
      ".*"
    ]
  }
  chrome {
    // The flags which will be passed to chromium when launching
    flags = [
      "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
      "--start-maximized",
      "--kiosk",
      "--enabled",
      "--disable-infobars",
      "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required"
    ]
  }
  stats {
    enable-stats-d = true
  }
  webhook {
    // A list of subscribers interested in receiving webhook events
    subscribers = []
  }
  jwt-info {
    // The path to a .pem file which will be used to sign JWT tokens used in webhook
    // requests.  If not set, no JWT will be added to webhook requests.
    # signing-key-path = "/path/to/key.pem"

    // The kid to use as part of the JWT
    # kid = "key-id"

    // The issuer of the JWT
    # issuer = "issuer"

    // The audience of the JWT
    # audience = "audience"

    // The TTL of each generated JWT.  Can't be less than 10 minutes.
    # ttl = 1 hour
  }
  call-status-checks {
    // If all clients have their audio and video muted and if Jibri does not
    // detect any data stream (audio or video) coming in, it will stop
    // recording after NO_MEDIA_TIMEOUT expires.
    no-media-timeout = 30 seconds

    // If all clients have their audio and video muted, Jibri consideres this
    // as an empty call and stops the recording after ALL_MUTED_TIMEOUT expires.
    all-muted-timeout = 10 minutes

    // When detecting if a call is empty, Jibri takes into consideration for how
    // long the call has been empty already. If it has been empty for more than
    // DEFAULT_CALL_EMPTY_TIMEOUT, it will consider it empty and stop the recording.
    default-call-empty-timeout = 30 seconds
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be copied in part, or in full, from [another source](https://community.jitsi.org/t/tutorial-jibri-overview-troubleshooting-tips-tricks-solve-your-jibri-problems-quickly/86054?page=5) without giving credit or offering a link. Do you have permission to redistribute this code without permission?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.